# Android application compiled and installed successfully but cannot be launch, stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, arduino

I am trying to make a simple android application to simulate a remote control, each button press will send a command to the arduino connecting to the local network.

I downloaded the source code and tried to modify it. However, when I increase the number of buttons, it builds successfully but cannot launch.

The source code has only 2 buttons. My modification has some 15 buttons. 
[Here is the link to the modified source.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2EnbPr0ZmbkcmIzUG5DaGJ1TEE/view?usp=sharing) Can anyone explain why it won't launch?

here is the logcat

```
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318): Process: com.android.arduino, PID: 7318
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.arduino/com.android.arduino.ArduinoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at com.android.arduino.ArduinoActivity.onCreate(ArduinoActivity.java:494)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
02-01 00:25:16.741: E/AndroidRuntime(7318):     ... 11 more

below is the code from java file, the original source code, I can run this code on mobile, I modify the code by adding more button in layout file and just imitate to make more button as the original code, however, it does not work

```
package com.android.arduino;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;



import java.net.*;


import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArduinoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button on;
Button off;
Button on1;
Button off1;


String serverHostname1;
DatagramSocket d1;
InetAddress ip,retiip;
DatagramPacket send,rec;
String modifiedSentence;
private Boolean isOnline()  {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(ni != null && ni.isConnected())
                return true;

            return false;
        }

public void led(String s) throws Exception
{

    byte[] b=(s.getBytes());
    if(isOnline())
    {

   // byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024]; 

    serverHostname1 = new String ("192.168.1.38");
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ip = InetAddress.getByName(serverHostname1); 
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ip",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   //try{

    d1 = new DatagramSocket();//}
   //catch(Exception e){
     //  e.printStackTrace();
       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //}

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"socket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        send =  new DatagramPacket(b,b.length, ip, 8032);   
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"packet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    d1.send(send); 
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  //rec =  new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    d1.setSoTimeout(10000);
    d1.receive(rec); 
    modifiedSentence =   new String(rec.getData());
    InetAddress returnIPAddress = rec.getAddress();
    //int port = rec.getPort();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reply:"+modifiedSentence,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reply from Server:"+returnIPAddress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    d1.close(); 
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No network",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    on=(Button)findViewById(R.id.on);
    off=(Button)findViewById(R.id.off);
    on1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.on1);
    off1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.off1);


    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //ArduinoActivity a=new ArduinoActivity();

                led("1");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Error::"+e);
            }

        }
    });


    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //ArduinoActivity b=new ArduinoActivity();
                led("2");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Error::"+e);
            }

        }
    });
    on1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //ArduinoActivity a=new ArduinoActivity();

                led("3");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ON",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Error::"+e);
            }

        }
    });


    off1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //ArduinoActivity b=new ArduinoActivity();
                led("4");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Error::"+e);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Please post your logcat error trace then only we shall be able to help you.

Comment: there might me some error that causing your application to break. did u enable logcat?

Comment: no no, they mean run it again, the errors the pile up in your ddms logcat section copy and paste it here..

Comment: it seems I'm finding it hard to add code in the post though

Comment: NPE ArduinoActivity line 494 in the onCreate() method. You're not instantiating something and calling a method on it.

Comment: @kleinsenberg I've just added the source code, I modify it by adding more button code in java file and layout file. However, it does not work as the source code

Comment: @DatTranThanh can you post your layout file and what line 494 is? I'm thinking you're missing one of the views in the xml, and it's null.

Comment: @kleinsenberg Thanks for pointing me how to check logcat, now I see the problem in line 494